# Multiple if statements in a flutter image widget

Tags: flutter

[image]

this is my code in flutter, I'm trying to display an image using 2 if conditions based on the chosen currency, I'm not getting the correct output. i know something is wrong in the code.

Comment: Wrap your whole condition Statments in brackets.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the tenary expression too complicated, i would suggest you to use function instead:

```
String _cryptoImage(String cryptoName){
  String imageUrl = coinList[3].imageUrl;

  if(cryptoName == 'btc') imageUrl = coinList[0];
  else if(cryptoName == 'eth') imageUrl = coinList[1];

  return imageUrl;
}

CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: _cryptoImage(ownedCryptoDB[index])
```